# Issue with react-pdf PDFDownloadLink onClick Event - "Check Internet Connection" Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, react-pdf

I'm working with the `react-pdf` library and attempting to add a custom `onClick` event handler to the PDFDownloadLink component. The goal is to trigger a custom download action when the user clicks to download the PDF. However, when I add the onClick handler, I encounter an error message that says, "Check Internet Connection." Strangely, if I remove the onClick event, the file downloads correctly.

[image]

Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
<div key={uuid()} className={classes.__wrapper}>
  <PDFDownloadLink
    onClick={onDownload} // Problematic onClick
    style={{ textDecoration: "none", color: "black" }}
    fileName={`${sku}.pdf`}
    document={<PDFDocument pages={pages} />}
  >
    {({ loading, blob }) =>
      loading ? <PDFLoader /> : <FileDownloadLink blob={blob} sku={sku} />
    }
  </PDFDownloadLink>

</div>
```

The `onDownload` function is meant to handle the download logic, and it works fine when not used in the onClick event. I suspect that there might be an issue with how the onClick event is being handled.

Can someone help me understand why adding the onClick event is causing this error, and how I can resolve it to trigger the custom download action successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I digged a bit deeper in the source code, as I was actually having the same issue. I mean I needed to perform some action when I get the downloaded file. The onClick also sends event: MouseEvent and instance: ReactPDF.BlobProviderParams

so you can have a function like that

```
const generatePdfSuccess = async (
    event: MouseEvent,
    instance: ReactPDF.BlobProviderParams
  ) => {
    if (instance.loading || !instance.url) {
      return;
    }
    downloadURI(instance.url, `filename.pdf`);
    closeModal();
    // or anything else you want to happen after download
  };
```

and because onClick would prevent the regular download from the library you can use function like the below to download this file with your code

```
function downloadURI(uri: string, name: string) {
  const link = document.createElement("a");
  link.href = uri;
  link.download = name;
  link.click();
}
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same issue and while I don't know what causes the error (I assume it's something to do with the `<PDFDownloadLink />` event handler clashing with the custom even handler in some way?)

However, I found that by instead of directly passing the `<PDFDocument />` to the `document` attribute, by passing a reference to a method that returns the `<PDFDocument />` I was able to run some custom actions before downloading the PDF.

For example, in your code, remove the `onClick` click event and add a function that returns `<PDFDocument pages={pages} />`:

```
const handlePdfDownload = () => {
   // Run custom code here
   //
   //
   return (<PDFDocument pages={pages} />)
}

<div key={uuid()} className={classes.__wrapper}>
   <PDFDownloadLink
      style={{ textDecoration: "none", color: "black" }}
      fileName={`${sku}.pdf`}
      document={handlePdfDownload()}
   >
      {({ loading, blob }) =>
         loading ? <PDFLoader /> : <FileDownloadLink blob={blob} sku={sku} />
      }
   </PDFDownloadLink>
</div>
```

I'm not sure if this would work in your use case, but I couldn't find much about this issue with this library online so though I'd throw in my two cent.